# What data access technology should I use

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Am working with a new client who's IT is a bit stone age to say the least. What should I be using as a modern data access layer... EF ADO OLEDB?

They are Oracle house.... with most apps in Winforms / vb6/rdo/ado/odbc

I have chance to reform some apps...so was thinking .net 4.5 winforms then  moving to web pages/ MVC. Thus I can I can do it in 2 stages ie EF with Winforms and then later application rewrites can be done in Web Pages / MVC

Does this seem right approach? My strategy is to slowly move them to more modern technologies by building up the layers / classes to handle the applications by creating a domain of classes that can be reused.

Comment: Actually WinForms is also quite old (but still used very much in current projects). The latest technology from Oracle would be ODP.NET Managed Driver (Oracle Data Provider for .NET), but it has still some limitations and a few bugs. Unmanaged ODP.NET is still a good choice. "EF", "MVC" and "LINQ" are no access technologies for Oracle.

Comment: I worked in a Microsoft/Oracle house (8i on the back-end). I used BOTH ADO and DAO, depending on the situation. If there was something I couldn't accomplish with DAO, I'd switch over and try an ADO solution. Between the two there wasn't much I couldn't accomplish. HTH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search reveals that Oracle provides a Entity Framework provider for Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm

Yes, Entity Framework works with both windows applications and web application.

Entity Framework is Microsoft's recommended data access solution on the Microsoft stack, but it is your job to evaluate the alternatives. How will it fit into your world? There is no easy answer, you need to experiment a bit and try the different solutions out.

Good luck.